# How to grep elixir installed packages using Bash

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I try to greb the installed elixir framework which is Phoenix Framework using `dpkg -l | grep phoenix`, but it does not log anything on terminal. Usually if we use grep to check if packages exists is as easy as `dpkg -l | grep name` but now it don't work.

So how do you check if elixir packages has been installed (Phoenix Framework, as example) using bash and log it to terminal?

Comment: `dpkg` tells you what you installed using `dpkg` (or a frontend like Apt, Software Center, etc) but if you installed it by other means, of course `dpkg` will not know anything about that.

Comment: For what it's worth, `dpkg` is specific to Debian and Debian-derived distros, and which shell you are using is by and large irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of “elixir packages” and most packages are project-wide. Phoenix, OTOH, as `hex` itself, and some other utility packages require system-wide installation for use as *archives*.

To list archives installed to your system, you can use `mix archive` command (assuming [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is installed and hence `mix` is available.)